# Which of these two sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

1. He begins to know his surroundings.
2. I have begun understanding this lesson since first session.

Comment: They're both grammatical, but that's as far as it goes. They both sound like they would require some very special circumstances to be idiomatic, or else something a non-native speaker might say.

Comment: @Robusto, in the 2nd example, you agree with using no article with "session"? It sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @ThePhoton: It's a normal elision. You will often hear constructions like "I've had a headache since first period," etc. It's not much of a stretch to substitute *session* for period there.

Comment: To this US English speaker, using *session* without an article sounds a little odd, but not impossible, for the reason Robusto says.

Answer (score 1):

> He begins to know his surroundings.

is grammatically correct, but native speakers would not use this construction. In the present tense, *He is beginning to know his surroundings* would be normal phrasing.

That construction would normally only be found as a clause in a larger context, in a conditional or some other sentence with additional components, for example:

> When *he begins to know his surroundings*, then ...
>   As *he begins to know his surroundings*, ...

The second sentence

> I have begun understanding this lesson since first session.

is not grammatically correct - *first session* requires the definite article (*the*).

> I have begun understanding this lesson since *the* first session.

However, this construction is also not normal phrasing. A more typical phrasing would be

> I have understood this lesson since the first session.

but given that the question seems to be around the use of *begin*, to emphasize that the commencement of understanding of the lesson is linked to the first session, use the imperfect form *began*:

> I began understanding this lesson in the first session.

Answer (score -1):

**"Begin to do"** is used for a **specific** situation.

**"Begin doing"** is usually used to make a **general** statement, in which the action that is done is repeated or regular or habitual.

So the first sentence would sound a little bit weird to me, because it miss the part that specify its meaning.
For example "As he **begins to** wake up, he can hear people talking all around him."

And for the second one, it seems correct both grammatically and situationally

*"I have begun understanding this lesson since first session"*. (= I began understanding the lesson as an activity or skill, that is, as something i did regularly and repeatedly since first session.)